# Trying to set & send a state variable as an URL string in a POST request with a single button click

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-state

Two buttons with its own function excuected when clicked, one is savedays and other is submitdays. I want to combine the functions so its only one button.

```
  const [days, setDays] = useState({
    Monday: false,
    Tuesday: false,
    Wednesday: false,
    Thursday: false,
    Friday: false,
    Saturday: false,
    Sunday: false,
  });
  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState("");

  const saveDays = async () => {
    await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => "");

    if (days.Monday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("MON,"));
    }
    if (days.Tuesday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("TUE,"));
    }
    if (days.Wednesday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("WED,"));
    }
    if (days.Thursday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("THUR,"));
    }
    if (days.Friday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("FRI,"));
    }
    if (days.Saturday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("SAT,"));
    }
    if (days.Sunday == true) {
      await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.concat("SUN,"));
    }
    await setSelectedDays((selectedDays) => selectedDays.slice(0, -1));
    console.log(selectedDays, "updated");
  };

  const submitDays = async () => {
    let postRes = await fetch(`/addSurveyDays/${selectedDays}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    let postResult = await postRes.json();
    if (postResult.success) {
      console.log("succes posted");
    } else console.log("Something went wrong, please try again");
  };

      <button
        type="button"
        className="greyBtn"
        id="saveBtn"
        onClick={async () => {
          await saveDays();
        }}
      >
        Save
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="greyBtn"
        id="saveSubmitBtn"
        onClick={async () => {
          await submitDays();
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
```

But when i combine both this functions to be executed on click with a single button. I get this error the first time i run it.

Chrome console log, `"POST HTTP://localhost:3000/addSurveyDays/ 404 (Not Found)`

The error is only there the first time i run it, then its fine. can someone help explain why that is?

There are 7 other buttons, each one for the day of the week and when clicked turn their respective day on. Example: days.Monday would turn true when its button is clicked

Comment: Looks like `selectedDays` is empty (i.e. `""`).

Comment: At the end of the save days, its gonna be something like 'MON,THUR'. I only did it empty at the beginning to empty the string. The if statements should add onto the string but it doesnt seem like it is

Comment: Could you share the rest of your code? Try to remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: I added some extra info, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply (1) add your logic for building the selected days string into a click handler and then (2) trigger an effect which will send a POST request after each change of the `selectedDays` state variable.

```
const App = () => {
  const [days, setDays] = useState({
    Monday: false,
    Tuesday: false,
    Wednesday: false,
    Thursday: false,
    Friday: false,
    Saturday: false,
    Sunday: false,
  });
  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState("");

  useEffect(async () => {
    let postRes = await fetch(`/addSurveyDays/${selectedDays}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      },
    });
    let postResult = postRes.json();
    if (postResult.success) {
      console.log("succes posted");
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong, please try again");
    }
  }, [selectedDays]);

  const handleSaveAndSubmit = () => {
    let newSelectedDays = "";

    Object.keys(days).forEach((day) => {
      if (days[day]) {
        newSelectedDays = newSelectedDays.concat(
          day.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase() + ","
        );
      }
    });
    console.log(newSelectedDays, "updated");
    setSelectedDays(newSelectedDays.slice(0, -1));
  };

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="greyBtn"
      id="saveSubmitBtn"
      onClick={handleSaveAndSubmit}
    >
      Save and Submit
    </button>
  );
};
```

---

> The error is only there the first time i run it, then its fine. can someone help explain why that is?

That's simply due to the fact that you can't access the *updated* state variable in a React functional component from your *current* scope.

In your case, you're assuming that `selectedDays` gets updated when you call `setSelectedDays()` and that you can access the updated value from your current state. You can't do that. It doesn't matter how long you wait (note that putting `await` in front of the state update functions has no effect, since they're not `Promise`es).

See: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) for more info.